# Pass object id to session storage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, object, local-storage

I have a simple function to post the selected object ID to session storage it works well as numbers but when i change it to a word it dose not work, any idea why and how to fix it?

I thought it would be fine as they are both a string, as you can see my function at the bottom parse the json, I dont see why it only works for numbers ?

**Code**

```
$scope.productsandformats = [{
    "name": "name 1",
    "format": [{
        "Fname": "test (ROADSIDE TEMP)",
        "id": "Roadside"
    }, {
        "Fname": "test Sheet",
        "id": "2"
    }, {
        "Fname": "Wrap test (Digital)",
        "id": "3"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "name 2,
    "format": [{
        "Fname": "2 test",
        "id": "4"
    }, {
        "Fname": "test Live (Digital)",
        "id": "5"
    }]
};
$scope.productTypeChange = function() {
    $scope.formats = $scope.productsandformats.find(ps => ps.name === $scope.formData.ProductType.name)
        //NG-Change
    $scope.myFunc = function() {
        var jsonItem = JSON.parse($scope.formData.formatType.id);
        sessionStorage.setItem('format', jsonItem);
    }
}
});
```

**I Get a error in inspector**

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()

Comment: Check that the input to `JSON.parse` is valid JSON. Also your code sample is missing a `"` after `name 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID you are parsing isn't JSON, that's why you're getting the error.

In point of fact the whole scope object is just a JavaScript object, not JSON (which is a text format).

The Id that you get is the string "Roadside", but if it's a JSON string it'd look something like "{ \"key\": \"value\" }".  The fact that it's missing the opening brace tells the parser it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try the below json in `$scope`

```
$scope.productsandformats =[{
    "name": "name 1",
    "format": [{
        "Fname": "test (ROADSIDE TEMP)",
        "id": "Roadside"
    }, {
        "Fname": "test Sheet",
        "id": "2"
    }, {
        "Fname": "Wrap test (Digital)",
        "id": "3"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "name 2",
    "format": [{
        "Fname": "2 test",
        "id": "4"
    }, {
        "Fname": "test Live (Digital)",
        "id": "5"
    }]
}]
```